# Dynamically allocating limited disk space per user on NTFS

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems, ntfs

I'm designing a module that needs to allocate dynamic, limited disk space per user.
Based on a large NTFS filesystem, I want each user to tell me how much space he want's extended to him, and then send him a path which he cannot fill over the predefined quota, and also, he wouldn't be able to access other folders/paths on the FS.
My main goal is to give users the ability to manually copy files from their workstations to the FS.
Once the user is done copying I want the quota to disappear and all the unused space to "merge" back with the rest of the FS. This can happen with a fairly large amount of users and to be done by code accessed by a web service..

I read about allocating quotas on NTFS partitions but i't seems a bit strange to create one each time..
Is there a best practice of doing this? Or a built-in (on win server 2008) technology to do so?
It seems like a pretty common task. I'm just not much of a storage expert.
Thanks!
Pavel.